# CSS 100% Height Column with Image

Tags: html, css, height

I've been trying a few techniques, but I'm getting stuck on this problem. I want to do the whole 100% height columns within a section thing, *but* one column has an image which needs to scale to fill one column.

So I have one column of text (variable content from WordPress) that is 66% wide and one column that holds an image and is 33% wide. The image can be on the left or the right based on a class.

My HTML:

```
<section class="page-section color-brand left-image image-third">
    <div class="page-section-mid-wrapper">
        <div class="image-wrapper left-image image-third">
            <img src="img.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="page-section-wrapper">
            <div class="page-section-content">
                Variable content here
            </div>
         </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Most of the CSS techniques do tricks to get a solid background color in both columns. But in this case, I want a scaled image. I'm willing to switch from an `img` tag to an inline `style="background-image"` to get the scaling to work, but either way, I'm having trouble getting the column heights to match.

The closest solution was to use `display:table`, but I don't like that I can't change which side the image is on without changing the HTML. With my current `float` based design, I can swap the image placement with just a different class (the `left-image` above for example).

With just floats, here is an example of what I have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/no80ayc2/2/
You'll notice that when the view is narrow, the image is shorter than the overall container height.

I've read something about using relative/absolute positioning, but the only way I could get that to work was with a fixed height for the container. That won't work for me: http://jsfiddle.net/qLa4g7fL/1/

**EDIT: To clarify, I want the image to fill the entire space (33% width by 100% height). And I expect it to get cropped as necessary.**

Here is an example of how that should look (just a quick idea)
[image: example]

Answer (score 0):

change `min-width: 100%` into `max-width:100%`  in `.page-section.image-third .image-wrapper img`

Then your image-wrapper may not have the full height but will stop your image to overflow.

Comment: As stated above, this: "Then your image-wrapper may not have the full height but will stop your image to overflow." is exactly what I'm trying to avoid. I want the image at full height, cropping is acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

```
 You need to change your min-width to max-width,
 Try to look at this link, I just update your code

 http://jsfiddle.net/no80ayc2/7/
```

Comment: No, that's the opposite of what I want. I want the image to fill the space, even if it has to be cropped. It should fill 100% of the height of the div containing the text and it should be 33% of the width of that section.

Answer (score 0):

There's a new amazing css property called object-fit!

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/object-fit/

You'll fall in love!